# Distribution of norm of random matrix

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable

I am curious to know whether central-limit theorem like considerations hold true for special functions like the norm of a matrix.

Specifically, I'm interested in the [Spectral norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html) of a matrix 
$$\|M^\prime\| = \text{Max eigenvalue of } (M^{\prime H}M^\prime),$$
where $(\bullet)^H$ represents the conjugate of the transpose of $(\bullet)$. Here, $M^\prime$ is close to matrix $M$ such that each element of ${M}^\prime$ has random error ${M}^\prime_{ij} = \mathcal{N}(M_{ij}, \sigma^2)$.

Question: **Will the distribution of $\|\tilde{M}\|$, which is a function of random variables $\tilde{M}_{ij}$ be a normal distribution?** I have tried to figure this out numerically. My numerics fit the normal distribution rather well. Is there a way to prove this analytically?

Comment: Some magic words to get you started are *Marchenko-Pastur* and *Wigner semicircle distribution*. The classical theory takes as a basic point of departure random matrices with mean-zero entries.